# Django 1.7 migrations and flush

Tags: python, django, data-migration, django-1.7

I have an app that uses initial models (auth.Group). Prior to django 1.7, I used `Group.objects.get_or_create` in the 'models.py'. This was ugly but worked most of the time. Changes to the app loading in django 1.7 broke this.

Now I am trying to use [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to provide these groups. This works the first time `./manage migrate` is run. However, when I run `./manage.py flush` the groups are missing. Running `./manage migrate` again also does not create them. What I want is to have this data in place after `./manage flush`.

I can see why django acts like this, but is there some way to flag a migration as always needing to be rerun? Is this some way to have these groups in place always in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [post_migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal is a good candidate to recreate your Groups.